# Creating custom Dojo widgets

Tags: dojo

I'm new to Dojo world. I tried to create a custom dojo widget from scratch.The problem that I'm facing is the widget is not getting parsed. I see that `postCreate` method of that widget is not getting called. The widget JS file is being downloaded from the server.

Here are the steps what I followed.

1. Created a JavaScript file CustomWidget.js in test folder.

   ```js
   dojo.provide('test.CustomWidget'); 
   dojo.require('dijit._Widget');

   dojo.declare('test.CustomWidget', dijit._Widget, {

       text: "Hello World",

       postCreate: function() {
           console.log(this.text+'text');
           this.domNode.innerHTML=this.text;
       }
   });
   ```
2. In my jsp file,I imported test.CustomWidget using `dojo.require`.

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript">

       dojo.require('test.CustomWidget');

       dojo.addOnLoad(function(){ dojo.parser.parse("addFavorites"); });
   </script>
   <div id='addFavorites' dojoType='test.CustomWidget'>
   </div>
   ```

I can see that CustomWidget.js file is being downloaded, but I don't see the console statement being printed. Can someone plese help me?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you aren't instantiating the widget, do you have code like this somewhere?

```
<div dojoType="mindtree.CustomWidget">...</div>
```

Otherwise it's like declaring a class but never calling new.